# Late Binding and WithEvents using VBA

Tags: c#, vba, com, interop

I have a requirement that I *think* I have a solution for, but I would appreciate input in case I'm missing something or setting myself up for failure down the road.

**The Requirement**

Implement some new business logic in a new library (using C#) that reports back its status through events. The library will be invoked from an existing VBA solution (can't change that - yet). The library is exposed to VBA via COM Interop - no issues here.

In addition to the "base" functionality exposed by this new library, I need to allow for the base functionality to be replaced by "custom" functionality down the road.

Both the base and custom functionality will implement the same Interface, but the internal private methods of each will be different for a variety of reasons.

**In VBA**

I need to be able to invoke either the base library or custom library (and perhaps other custom libraries that implement the same Interface in the future). If it weren't for the requirement to respond to and display messages from the libraries I could just use Late Binding to instantiate the object at runtime. However, since I need to respond to the events that are raised by the libraries I need to use the `WithEvents` keyword when declaring the variable in VBA.

If I only had to support the base library I could do something like the following:

```vb
Private WithEvents Processor As MyDefault.RuleEngine

Public Sub Execute(StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date, SomeOtherParms As String)
Set Processor = New MyDefault.RuleEngine
Processor.Execute StartDate, EndDate, SomeOtherParms
End Sub

Private Sub Processor_OnProgressUpdate(ByVal percentComplete As Double)

'Show the progress on the UI to the user

End Sub
```

Since I have to support custom implementations of this library (some of which I know about now, others that I don't yet know about) I would *like* to use late binding to handle this scenario.

However, WithEvents cannot be used with Late Binding, though I may have stumbled upon a workaround.

In my scenario, I will **always** have a reference to the base implementation. It will only be under specific, configured circumstances where the base functionality will be replaced by a custom implementation.

Since the base and custom library(ies) share the same Interface, I have the following code working in a proof of concept:

```vb
Private WithEvents Processor As MyDefault.RuleEngine

Public Sub Execute(StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date, SomeOtherParms As String)

If CustomConditionIsMet Then
   'In real-life we'll look this info up from a table or config file
   Set Processor = CreateObject("MyCustom.RuleEngine")
Else
   Set Processor = New MyDefault.RuleEngine
End If

Processor.Execute StartDate, EndDate, SomeOtherParms

End Sub

Private Sub Processor_OnProgressUpdate(ByVal percentComplete As Double)

'Show the progress on the UI to the user

End Sub
```

This implementation works without errors (both at compile and runtime), but I am a bit hesitant about using this solution going forward because I don't feel like I have a solid understanding of how \ why this actually works. My suspicion is that it works because both the base and custom libraries share the same interface, so COM is "happy" with late binding via the `CreateObject` statement, but I'm afraid of what I might be missing here that will potentially cause me grief down the road.

**My Question**

Is it "safe" to rely upon this workaround for late binding using `WithEvents`, and if so, why?

If not, are there any alternatives that I could look to implement (beyond not using VBA, which I don't have a choice of in this scenario)?

Comment: I'm not even going to pretend to know the answer, but I would think that so long as both classes use the same interface, you're fine. After all, it is a requirement to use an interface rather than a concrete implementation when using COM Interop. As far as VBA is concerned, they're the same type (essentially). Really interesting question by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Private WithEvents Processor...`

The `WithEvents` statement instructs to discover value events and connect them to the available code handlers. When you initialize `Processor` value, you will have the following actions taking place behind the scene: checking COM server class information, identification of events interface available, discovering connection point container, connecting to events of the found interface, providing a call back to receive event calls.

When/if all mentioned happens and succeeds, then events fired from COM server reach your handlers. On the VB.NET code side there are no additional assumption as for who exactly implements the events, so it is okay to switch servers on the go as long as they are valid COM servers with connection points and class/type information.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand how it works, you are correct in your guess. As long as a "custom" engine exposes all of the events and the properties of the engine that are accessed (called) by the VBA code accessing the engine, you will have no problem. I have not tried this but I am sure you can hedge by building into the standard class some generic events and properties (in name only) that you could actively utilize later one with one of the custom formulations.